# Completar a URL

Tags: funções, url

Criar uma função chamada dominio que receberá uma String  `br.NOMEDOSITE.com` e sua função será devolver "http://br.NOMEDOSITE.com".

Eu fiz assim:

```
function dominio ("br.NOMEDOSITE.com" ){
    conslole.log ("http://br.NOMEDOSITE.com")
}
```

Mas estou recebendo o erro:

> Unexpected string

Answer (score 1):

```
function dominio(url)
{
  if(url)
    return "http://" + url;
  else
    console.log(url+" não informada");
}

dominio("br.digitalhouse.com");
dominio("9gag.com");
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema está acontecendo porque na assinatura da função você não declarou um nome de parâmetro para ser passado um valor e sim uma String. Para solucionar este problema troque essa String por um nome **sem aspas**, dessa forma:

```
function dominio (url) {
    // ...
}
```

Você disse que o objetivo dessa função é retornar a string `"br.digitalhouse.com"` formatado, mas pense bem, você pode criar uma função que possa formatar não só esse endereço mas também outros. Veja abaixo a função que eu escrevi:

```js
function dominio (url) {

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }

    console.log(url);
    return url;
}
```